# Why does \left break TeX rendering?

Tags: delimiters

The following TeX breaks rendering, but if I remove the \left function, the TeX renders (but without the stretchy brace).  I'm helping a colleague and I'm too new to LaTeX and TeX to know how to approach fixing this.

```
\ \ \small{w_{1}[n] } = \left{ 
\begin{array}{ll} 
 1 & \ \ \small{n=0,1,...,12}\\
 0 & \ \ \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}
```

Comment: You are missing the matching `\right.` (an empty delimiter). Is this in a TeX document?

Answer (score 6):

You wrote `\left{ <stuff>`. TeX is trying to make `<stuff>` into a left delimiter because `{` opens a group. You probably meant to write `\left\{ <stuff>`.

Moreover, you probably should just be using the `cases` environment from `amsmath` instead.

Comment: Combine your answer with the egreg's comment above to get the pretty perfect answer! ;-)

Comment: I edited the TeX to this, but it still doesn't render.  \small{w_{1}[n] } = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 \ \ \small{n=0,1,...,12}\\0 \ \ \text{otherwise} \\\ \end \right {array}

Comment: @pwilkins `\right` also needs to be followed by a delimiter, e.g., `\right\}`. If you don't want a right delimiter use `\right.` (including the dot!).

Comment: Bingo! That's turned the trick. The original TeX didn't have the trailing brace so the 'dot' fixed it. Here's my working version:    $$ \small{w_{1}[n] } = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 \ \ \small{n=0,1,...,12}\\0 \ \ \text{otherwise} \\\ \end{array}\right. $$

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `\small` directive when TeX is in math mode can't work. (Moreover, the command `\small` is a switch and doesn't take an argument.) I suggest that you set up the MWE as follows instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ % begin display math
w_{1}[n]  = 
\begin{cases}
   1 & n=0,1,\dots,12\\
   0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\] % end display math
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that the question refers only to MathJax; where `\small` has no effect, in my experiment.

Comment: @egreg - in TeX's math mode, executing `\small` won't have an effect either, right?

Comment: It issues a warning: `LaTeX Font Warning: Command \small invalid in math mode'